# How to count number of swaps in Bubble Sort in Python

Tags: python, bubble-sort

```
def bubSort(numList):
    swapNumber = 0
    for valNum in range(len(numList)-1, 0, -1):
        for valNum2 in range(valNum):
            
            if numList[valNum2+1] < numList[valNum2]:
                
                placeholder = numList[valNum2]
                numList[valNum2] = numList[valNum2 + 1]
                numList[valNum2 + 1] = placeholder
                swapNumber+=1
                print(swapNumber)
                
            print(numList)
    return swapNumber

numList = [7,9,3,1,5,3,2]
bubSort(numList)
print(numList)
print(bubSort(numList))
```

I tried counting the number of swaps but I don't think its working right. It reads 15 during execution, but I think it's 10.

Also the value of the swapNumber isn't returning for some reason, it shows 0.

Comment: Why do you think it's not working right? What do you get and what did you expect instead?

Comment: Its showing 15 instead of , from what I can count, 10
The array its sorting is the numList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Correct count of Swaps:

I think the count of swaps is working right.

Hint: put your `print(numList)` just after or before your `print(swapNumber)`, at the same level of indentation (in the `if`), and you will see all steps.

If you look at what is printed in the console (the print instructions from the function itself), it matches.

## Return value of 0 at the end

Indeed there is something strange since your last `print(bubSort(numValues))` prints `0`.... instead of `15` (Ithat you can see during the history!)

The problem is that you call the function two times

```py
bubSort(numList)
print(numList)
print(bubSort(numList))
```

The second time, the list is *already sorted*, so no swap occurs!

You want to keep the value from the *first* time you call the function:

```py
numberOfSwaps = bubSort(numList)
print(numList)
print(numberOfSwaps)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bubSort function is returning the value and it is correct.
The problem is that, that you are calling the bubSort function twice on the same array and since the first array already make the array sorted so when you print(bubSort(numList)) it returns 0.

Remove or comment the first bubsort(numList) function and then check, it will return you 15, the no of swaps.

```
numList = [7,9,3,1,5,3,2]
# bubSort(numList)
print(numList)
print(bubSort(numList))
```

Comment: just a small remark: in this solution, you may want to print the list after it is sorted, so swap the last two lines